# Compare a column in one dataframe with two other columns in a different dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have created two data frames from two tsv files. The data frames are as follows:

```
Dataframe1 (df1)
chr    position
5      745
7      963
8      1024

Dataframe2 (df2)
chr    start    end
1      10       100
1      500      600
5      250      600
5      784      1045
7      98       980
7      11       85
8      450      1000
8      1546     1886
12     63       1400
```

Now, I want to create a new column of df1 which will give 'True' if for the same `chr` the position falls within the `start` and `end` (of df2). I am using the following code:

```
df1['Valid'] = np.where((df1['chr'] == df2['chr']) & (df1['position'] >= df2['start']) & (df1['position'] <= df2['end']),'True','False')
```

This is not working and giving the error message - ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects. How to do this?

Expected output is:

```
Dataframe1 (df1)
chr    position    Valid
5      745         False
7      963         True
8      1024        False
```

Comment: This is really {5: [False, False], 7: [True, False], 8: [False, False]}. For example, with chr 7 and position 963, it is valid for the [98, 980] interval but not valid for [11, 85]. This is OK if you say that it is valid if _all_ values from `df2` match or if _any_ value matches.

Comment: Yes that is true, but I am printing the True false on df1 and yes, it there is a True then it should be printed. (if it is within any region)

Comment: your updated df2 is confusing, df2 has two chr=7 and accoring to the one df1's 'Valid" column should be 'True' while with the second one should be 'False'.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I am trying by concatenating the start and end and using .tolist()

Comment: so what the value of 'Valid' be against 'chr=7' and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge the dataframes, evaluate, then drop the unused columns.

```
>>> (df1
 .merge(df2, on='chr', how='left')
 .assign(Valid=lambda df: df.eval('start <= position <= end'))
 .drop(columns=['start', 'end'])
)
   chr  position  Valid
0    5       745  False
1    7       963   True
2    8      1024  False
```

In the case of multiple `chr` values in `df2`, merge the `position` onto `df2`, evaluate each, and then group on `chr` and determine if any position is valid.  Assign the result back to `df1`:

```
valid = (
    df2
    .merge(df1, on='chr', how='right')
    .assign(Valid=lambda df: df.eval('start <= position <= end'))
    .groupby('chr')['Valid'].any()
)
>>> df1.merge(valid, left_on='chr', right_index=True)
   chr  position  Valid
0    5       745  False
1    7       963   True
2    8      1024  False
```

Comment: There are multiple entries of the same 'chr' in df2. Will this work in that case?

Comment: If there are multiple entries, against which are you evaluating?  You could first group `df2` on `chr` and take the max and min values.

Comment: That will not be correct as there may be excluded regions. I have updated df2 in the question.

Comment: have alook at my solution

Answer (score 0):

Have a look:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'chr': [5,7,8],
                   'position': [745, 963,1024]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'chr': [1,5,7,8,12],
                   'start': [10,250,98,450,63],
                    'end':[100,600,980,1000,1400]})

df2 = df2.loc[df2['chr'].isin(df1.chr)].reset_index(drop=True)

df1['Valid'] = np.where((df1['chr'] == df2['chr']) & (df1['position'] >= df2['start']) & (df1['position'] <= df2['end']),'True','False')
print(df1)
```

and the output:

```
   chr  position  Valid
0    5       745  False
1    7       963   True
2    8      1024  False
```

Comment: Re-check your output.

Comment: The second entry in the output should be True as 963 is between the given range of 98 and 980 for chr 7.

Comment: The error is still appearing - ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: Make sure you are using the revised `df2`, not the one you are using.

Comment: you have updated your df2 and the question but have introduced a confusion. Have alook at my comment under your question

Answer (score 0):

I use `map` and boolean mask with `any` and `groupby`

```
s = df2.chr.map(df1.set_index('chr').position)
df1['Valid'] =  df1.chr.map(((s>=df2.start) & (s<=df2.end)).groupby(df2.chr).any())

Out[340]:
   chr  position  Valid
0    5       745  False
1    7       963   True
2    8      1024  False
```